# In which dataset a data mining algorithm performs well?

Tags: classification, data-mining

I know my question is so generally it depends on dataset but my question is performance of an data mining algorithm depends on structure of dataset for example size of dataset،number of feature،missing values،outliers،type of feature ،synthetic data and ،.... I want to know these structure metrics if know some book or paper about this subject please informe me

Comment: The question could be better suited for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. But there are dozens of data mining algorithms, and dozens of possible metrics (or "quality measures") that one could apply for each of them. As such, the question of far too broad. (I've been working on that topic recently, but no results published so far)

Comment: I am working on classification algorithm in my project c4.5 svm cart naive bayes and knn I performance metric like accuracy ،recall... But I want to know why this algorithm performes well in one dataset what elements in a dataset cause this result

Comment: Again: In that general form, you can invest *years* of research and *years* of coding into that question. A quick glimpse at one of the things that I'm working on: http://javagl.de/ClassifierEval001.gif You can generate artificial data sets (in 3D in this case) consisting of gaussian blobs of data elements. In this application, you can move the center of one blob, and observe about a dozen of quality metrics for a NaiveBayes classifier changing accordingly. For example, accuracy approaches 1.0 when the blobs are completely separated in one dimension. And that's only the tip of the iceberg.